# How to differentiate between valid DateTime-string and plain string?

Tags: c#

I have to check whether a value in a loop is a plain `string` or it can be converted to a `DateTime`. But `DateTime.TryParse` even accepts "1/10".

```
List<string> lst = new List<string>() { "1/1/2016 12:00:00 AM", "1/10" };
foreach (string item in lst)
{
   DateTime dt;
   if (DateTime.TryParse(item, out dt))
   {
     //Pick date values and do something
   }
   else
   {
     //Do something with string value
   }
}
```

Can someone help me , how can it be ?

Comment: `DateTime.TryParse` or `DateTime.TryParseExact`?

Comment: the values are coming from a loop. datetime parse validates the 2nd one as date.

Comment: List<string> lst = new List<string>() { "1/1/2016 12:00:00 AM", "1/10" };
                foreach (string item in lst)
                {
                    DateTime dt;
                    if (DateTime.TryParse(item, out dt))
                    {
                        //Pick date values and do something
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //Do something with string value
                    }
                }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the values are coming from a loop. datetime parse validates the 2nd
>   one as date

You can use `DateTime.TryParseExact` instead of `DateTime.TryParse`:

```
string[] strings = {"1/1/2016 12:00:00 AM", "1/10" };
foreach (var str in strings)
{
    DateTime dt;
    if (DateTime.TryParseExact(str, "d/M/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None , out dt))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("is a date: " + str);
    }
}
```

With `TryParse` even `"1/10"` is accepted as a valid DateTime.

Comment: Yes, that is my problem 1/10 is also becoming valid datetime format